# Create custom layout with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, javascript

As a side project, I am learning to work with OpenLayers and I am trying to replicate the layout that is shown in these type of maps (see attached image)[image]

I have started to play with the JS following some tutorials and got this code:

```
import { Map, View } from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import './style.css';
import XYZ from 'ol/source/XYZ';

const blackAndWhiteLayer = new TileLayer({
  source: new XYZ({
    url: 'https://{a-c}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    maxZoom: 19,
  }),
});

const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    blackAndWhiteLayer,
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2,
  }),
});
```

It looks promising, but when I zoom in I see a lot of labels that don't want. How can I tune the output further apart from changing the baselayer to another source?

Comment: You can't change what you see on this layer. It's a raster layer and so it's content is fixed.

Comment: CartoDB has a `light_nolabels` style https://github.com/CartoDB/basemap-styles#1-web-raster-basemaps

Comment: maybe a basic question, but aren't those vector tiles?

Comment: If you look at the URL `https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/{style}/{z}/{x}/{y}{scale}.png`, the `.png` extension tells you they are raster tiles.